# Is this a good way to power my camera?

Tags: batteries, voltage-regulator, camera

I have a Canon SX210 IS which has not a connector to use a external power supply. So I wanted to connect "my" power source to the pins the battery usually touches.

In the back of my camera, it says 4.2 V but the battery has 3.7 (model NB-L5).

Right now, I have in my hands a voltage regulator (7805) and a diode which would drop 0.7 V. 
I plan to connect the 7805 to a car battery so there is no line noise. Do you know if it safe to feed my camera with those 4.3 V?

Should I use less voltage? Would the camera be damaged if I pass 4.2 V?

I haven't tried anything yet just for precaution.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Does somebody know about a voltage regultor with arround (3.8 - 4.3)V of output?

Comment: Any chance you could accept some answers?  It looks like you've asked 4 answers but haven't accepted any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The camera likely has a voltage regulator on board between the batteries and the main circuitry.  If you're able to find a part number on that, you should be able to find a datasheet for the part and that will tell you what the max / min input voltages are.

**EDIT:** I did some googling, and it looks like there is a power adapter you can purchase:

[http://www.amazon.com/Canon-ACK-DC30-Adapter-SD700IS-SD800IS/dp/B000EVLS3S](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000EVLS3S)

It's bloody expensive, but if you can find some specs on that power adapter, you should have a better idea of what you can supply the camera with safely.

**EDIT2*** I did some more searching, and it appears as though unit expects around 4.3 volts, so you should be good to go.

http://www.studio3d.com/download/canon_870_user-guide.pdf

> 4.3V DC 1.5A

I would think it would be easiest / most robust to just plug your power supply circuit into the DC jack.

Comment: I knew about that adapter, but like you said, it's way too expensive (and I don't want to know how much more here in Argentina). I tried to google for technical specs about it, but there is a endless list of pages to sell the product and no pages showing info (not even the output voltage!).

Comment: @Tomas - I found some specs and added a link.

Comment: There is no DC jack! If you see the product, they give you a fake battery body with a female plug in its back, where you can connect the plug. Because of that, I have to figure out how to connect some wires inside the camera.

Comment: Page 32 of the manual you gave me. Anyway, that info is good and should allow me to use the 7805 voltage regulator and a diode in serial.

Comment: @Tomas - sorry about the power jack... I saw one of the cameras had a picture of a jack and that stuck in my head.  Good luck!

Comment: This is super weird. I've connected my laptop charger to the regulator and the output shows 5 V right? But when I put the diode in serial, the voltage after the diode is 14 V. Why?

Comment: That sounds like another question to me (I can't help you with that one).